# A net is not a legal lvalue in this context [9.3.1(IEEE)]

Tags: verilog

Does anyone know how to fix this problem : i'm always getting this error message :

> A net is not a legal lvalue in this context [9.3.1(IEEE)]. and this is
>   my code

:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps 
 module dsm_egnfet_l150_w2_n16_dgc_t3 ( b, d, s, g );

inout  b, d, s;
input  g;

always 
begin
    if (g === 1) 
    s = d ;
end
   endmodule
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using `s` as an `inout` instead of an `output`, given that it has a fixed assignment?

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, actually, it s a transistor and the models comes like that i didn't design the input or the output i have only to debug... i changed that statement with a function already defined for verilog nmos(), pmos()... but now i have another issue here is the code :

 module dac (gnd,nw,pw,vdd,ip,sel,selb);
inout : gnd,nw,op,pw,vdd;
input ip,sel,selb;
initial 
begin 
if ((sel===1) && (selb===1)) || ((sel ===0) && (selb ===0))
not(op,ip);
end
endmodule
 
and the error is  : expecting a left parenthesis [12.1.2[7.1(IEEE)]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following instead of a procedural assignment:

`assign s = (g===1)?d:1'dz;`

Answer (score 0):

```
always @*
begin
  if (g==1)begin
    s=d;
  end
end 
endmodule
```

try this

Comment: This code won't compile for me on EDAplayground, as `s` is a net type, not a reg.

Comment: Although the SO is missing `@*`, your code will not work because a net can only be assigned continuously (`assign` statement), not procedural (`always` block). Technically there is a procedural assign (`assign` within an `always`), but this **should not** be use as it is scheduled for deprecation, may not always synthesize correctly if at all, and adds confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, actually, it s a transistor and the models comes like that i didn't design the input or the output i have only to debug... i changed that statement with a function already defined for verilog nmos(), pmos()... but now i have another issue here is the code :

  module dac (gnd,nw,pw,vdd,ip,sel,selb);
   inout : gnd,nw,op,pw,vdd;
   input ip,sel,selb;
   initial 
   begin 
   if ((sel===1) && (selb===1)) || ((sel ===0) && (selb ===0))
   not(op,ip);
   end
endmodule
 
and the error is  : expecting a left parenthesis [12.1.2[7.1(IEEE)]

Answer (score 0):

the solution was : 
"`timescale 1ns / 1ps

```
 module dsm_egnfet_l150_w2_n16_dgc_t3 ( b, d, s, g );

 inout  b, d, s;
 input  g;
 reg s1;

  assign s=s1;
  always @ *
  begin

  if (g === 1) 
   s1 = d ;
   end

   endmodule
```